# Let find only show the last item

Tags: bash, find

I think this is a tricky question.

I've got a directory containing N recursive subdirectories. E.g:

```
/tmp/dir1/dir2
/tmp/dir2
/tmp/dir3/dir4/.../dir7
/tmp/dir4/.../dirN
```

If I use find /tmp I get outputs like this:

```
/tmp/dir1
/tmp/dir1/dir2
/tmp/dir2
/tmp/dir3
/tmp/dir3/dir4
```

...

But I only want to get the full path of the last folder in the subtree, not the parent directories listed individually.

So in this case:

```
/tmp/dir1/dir2
/tmp/dir2
/tmp/dir3/dir4
```

I can't use mindepth and maxdepth, because I the amount of child-Folders is random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-links` option to filter out directories with only two links (one to the parent and one to itself) like so:

```
find dir -type d -links 2
```

The number of `links` a directory has is counted as a link to each sub-directory + a link to self + a link to parent. The latter two are always present so the link count for any directory is >= 2. For directories which have no other sub-directories the count is exactly 2 and that is what you want.

Comment: Thank you. As far as I can tell from a short test this solves my problem perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `find /tmp` has this output:

```
$ find /tmp
/tmp/dir1
/tmp/dir1/dir2
/tmp/dir2
/tmp/dir3
/tmp/dir3/dir4
```

you can add an awk filter to only print the last line of each category:

```
$ find /tmp | awk -F/ 'p!=$3&&NR>1{print l}{p=$3;l=$0}END{print l}'
/tmp/dir1/dir2
/tmp/dir2
/tmp/dir3/dir4
```